# PDO bindParam not working "bindParam() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mollie

I am trying out the Mollie payment processor for a CMS that I'm creating but I've ran into a problem. When I try to input the data into a MySQL database it does not do that. I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/examples/01-new-payment.php on line 83

This is the complete code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Example 1 - How to prepare a new payment with the Mollie API.
 */

$amount      = 100.50;
$description = "Booking for Villa Hijau";
$days        = 10;
$name        = "####";
$email       = "####";

try {
    /*
     * Initialize the Mollie API library with your API key.
     *
     * See: https://www.mollie.com/beheer/account/profielen/
     */
    include "initialize.php";

    /*
     * Generate a unique order id for this example. It is important to include this unique attribute
     * in the redirectUrl (below) so a proper return page can be shown to the customer.
     */
    $order_id = time();

    /*
     * Determine the url parts to these example files.
     */
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strcasecmp('off', $_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 0 ? "https" : "http";
    $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $path     = dirname(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    /*
     * Payment parameters:
     *   amount        Amount in EUROs. This example creates a € 10,- payment.
     *   description   Description of the payment.
     *   redirectUrl   Redirect location. The customer will be redirected there after the payment.
     *   webhookUrl    Webhook location, used to report when the payment changes state.
     *   metadata      Custom metadata that is stored with the payment.
     */
    $payment = $mollie->payments->create(array(
        "amount" => $amount,
        "description" => $description,
        "redirectUrl" => "{$protocol}://{$hostname}{$path}/03-return-page.php?order_id={$order_id}",
        "webhookUrl" => "{$protocol}://{$hostname}{$path}/02-webhook-verification.php",
        "metadata" => array(
            "order_id" => $order_id
        )
    ));

    /*
     * In this example we store the order with its payment status in a database.
     */
    database_write($order_id, $payment->status, $amount, $description, $days, $name, $email);

    /*
     * Send the customer off to complete the payment.
     */
    header("Location: " . $payment->getPaymentUrl());
}
catch (Mollie_API_Exception $e) {
    echo "API call failed: " . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
}


/*
 * NOTE: This example uses a text file as a database. Please use a real database like MySQL in production code.
 */
function database_write($order_id, $status, $amount, $description, $days, $name, $email)
{
    $db_user  = 'mollie';
    $db_pass  = '####';
    $order_id = intval($order_id);
    // Use $status to get the order status
    $dbh      = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=orders', $db_user, $db_pass);
    $stmt     = "INSERT INTO order (id, order_name, order_description, order_amount, order_customer, order_customer_email, order_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    if($stmt){
    $stmt->bindParam($order_id,$name,$description,$amount,$name,$email,$status);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
~ Rik

Comment: erm.... `INSER INTO order`??? missing a `T`

Comment: Changed but still not working

Comment: try having a `bindParam` for each parameter and, as noted by @Matt Musia - `prepare` the statement using `$dbh->prepare`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prepare your sql statement

```
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO order 
  (id, order_name, order_description, order_amount, order_customer, 
 order_customer_email, order_status) 
           VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

like suggested bu Fred-ii be careful because you are using the word "order",

this  is a MySQL reserved word,

then you should use backtics  around the this term

```
 `order`
```

Comment: These link could be useful http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php    or  http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php  and if my answer is right please mark it as accepted

Comment: Sidenote: OP is using `order` which is unquoted. Since it is a MySQL reserved word, it should be noted that it either requires it to be escaped/ticked, or renamed to something other than `order`. This, for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `bindParam()` on a string.

You have to use `PDO::prepare` first. See the doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: Thanks. It was explained in the answer from @scaiseEdge